# SQL stored procedure in ASPX not executing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure to convert an Excel file to SQL Server 2008 R2. It works perfectly when I test it in Visual Studio 2008.

However, when I use the stored procedure in an ASPX page using the `SqlDataSource` control, the stored procedure does not execute and no conversion happens, although there is no error message displayed. Here is the ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
         AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Processing.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="MyStoredProcedure" 
         SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

The SQL Server stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.MyStoredProcedure 
AS

SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[MySQLtable] 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\MyExceltable;', 
                'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
RETURN
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `C:MyExceltable` <-- That syntax seems a bit dodgy

Answer (score 1):

Is the aspx page being served from a server? If so the file (MyExceltable) needs to be on the server instead of the user's machine.

Comment: Yes the file in the server as well.

Comment: I also noticed that when I run the page, I don't notice any pause at all, which means the conversion did not occur as it takes a bit of a time to convert the Excel file to SQL table. Also, when I check the table properties, the time/date did not change. That I why I am sure the conversion did not happen.

Comment: Your stored procedure is an insert command.
It insert the records from the excel file into the table.
It does not fit into the Select Command. What you should probably do is alter the stored procedure to SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET...

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
SelectCommand="MyStoredProcedure"
```

Looking at your SQL script, this should be:

```
SelectCommand="StoredProcedureExcelToSQL"
```

Comment: Edited teh SQL script. Thanks. But still not worlking. :(